# Python - Find similar things in all dictionary values

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'first': ['cat', 'dog'], 'second': ['fish', 'cat']}
```

Is there something that will return 'cat'?
I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: I think that a function with a for-loop should do the job.

Answer (score 8):

See the documentation for [`set.intersection()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection), it very useful for finding common elements in sequences, and you can use either the method or the syntax `a & b` where both `a` and `b` are sets.

Here is a concise way to do what you want:

```
>>> set.intersection(*map(set, mydict.values()))
set(['cat'])
```

Or a potentially more readable solution that uses `reduce()`:

```
reduce(set.intersection, map(set, mydict.values()))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mydict = {'first': ['cat', 'dog'], 'second': ['fish', 'cat']}
def similar(x,y):return [c for c in set(x).intersection(set(y))]
reduce(similar, mydict.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> mydict = {'first': ['cat', 'dog'], 'second': ['fish', 'cat']}
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(i for v in mydict.values() for i in v)
>>> print [i for i in c if c[i]==len(mydict)]
['cat']
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way:

```
first = True
for x in mydict:
    if first:
        common = set(mydict[x])
        first = False
    else:
        common = common & set(mydict[x])
print common
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l2=[x for x in mydict.values()] 
dic = {}
for e in l2:
    for i in e:
        dic.setdefault(i,0)
        dic[i]+=1
for e in dic.items():
    if len(l2) == e[1]:
        print e[0] # cat
```